# 404 error with AJAX in ASP.NET Core & Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I have spent hours looking at other examples. I cannot get Ajax to work.

Here is a shot of my layout. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and ASP.NET Core.

Gurus - can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image: layout]

My bottom of `Create.cshtml`:

```
</script>
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("Okay");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:7103/HomeCascading/Get_3Data",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { name: "Smith" },
                success: function (res) {
                    alert("_a_Success_ " +res)
                },
                error: function (res) {
                    alert("_b_err_=_ " +res.d+" " +res)
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

This is part of `Program.cs`:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();;

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    areaName: "YourIrrFields",
    pattern: "{controller=HomeCascading}/{action=Create}");

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

And here is the method I'm trying to call

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Get_3Data(string name)
{
    string stTest = name;
    return Ok(name);
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by what you're trying to accomplish with the `MapAreaControllerRoute` call in the Program class. How does that line up with the `Get_3Data` method?

Comment: Error 404 indicates the file is not found.  With a controller this means the route in the config.cs doesn't have a corresponding file.  See following which explain the relationship between the route and the files : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mapping the controller wrongly and assuming an area. try changing
this.

```
app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    areaName: "YourIrrFields",
    pattern: "{controller=HomeCascading}/{action=Create}");
```

to this

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=HomeCascading}/{action=Create}");
```

if the controller is actually in an area then try changing this instead.

```
 url: "http://localhost:7103/HomeCascading/Get_3Data",
```

to this

```
 url: "http://localhost:7103/YourIrrFields/HomeCascading/Get_3Data",
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Area folder structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-7.0#area-folder-structure) we can see:

> Consider an app that has two logical groups, Products and Services.
> Using areas, the folder structure would be similar to the following:

[image]

Try to modify your structure like below:

[image]

Controller:

```
  [Area("YourIrrFields")]
    public class HomeCascadingController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Get_3Data(string name)
        {
            string stTest = name;
            //return Ok(name);
            return Json(name);
        }
    }
```

Note I add layout to the create view:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: I set it up this way. I never see the "_a_Success" message. I always get an error which is "undefined". When I inspect the page I get "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".  What am I missing?

Comment: @Steve42   try to add `https` like`url: "https://localhost:7103/HomeCascading/Get_3Data"`,

Comment: I get a "405" error. I  am going to start over with a new project and see if I can get it to working. Thanks for your help.